# Grails update html table ajax insert with message

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-orm

I'm come from a .net background to grails. I got a form for user to insert, and a html table with the list of records. Once user insert a new record, how do I update the html table with the record and display a message - e.g. company inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Create a domain class for inserting your records, with whatever properties you need. Read [Creating domain class](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-domain-class.html) and [Grails GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html)

Once the user submits your form insert the necessary values as a record into this. For getting the entire list of records you can call the [list()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html) method on your domain-class. Send the entire list of records to the client side as the response of the action /  render as a **model**. See [render.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html) Update your html table using these new records.

For the status part, you may want to do the insert operations in a **try-catch**  block and render a status a message accordingly.